# Undefined index: bsd while importing CSV file using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I am a complete noob to Laravel and am trying something here. I want to import a CSV file but when I submit it gives me this error

**Undefined index: bsd**

**my TransactionImport.php file**

```
<?PHP
 namespace App\Imports;
 use App\Transactions;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

 class TransactionsImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
 {
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Transactions([
        'bsd'     => $row['bsd'],
        'lodgement_reference'    => $row['lodgement_reference'], 
        'account_number'    => $row['account_number'],
        'account_name'    => $row['account_name'],
        'payment_description'    => $row['payment_description'],
        'amount'    => $row['amount'],
        'amount_of_with_holding_tax'    => $row['amount_of_with_holding_tax'],
    ]);
   }
 }
```

**ImportExportController.php file**

```
<?PHP

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Imports\TransactionsImport;
 use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

 class ImportExportController extends Controller
{
 /**
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
 public function importExportView()
 {
   return view('import');
 }


 /**
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
 */
  public function import() 
  {
    Excel::import(new TransactionsImport,request()->file('file'));
       
    return back();
  }
  }
```

**transactions.php Model file**

```
<?PHP

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Transactions extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'bsd', 'lodgement_reference', 'account_number', 'account_name', 'payment_description', 'amount', 'amount_of_with_holding_tax'
];
}
```

[image: importfile]

please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check with `dd($row);`

Comment: @sta this gives a this data array:7 [▼
  "013_664" => "013-040"
  "ref_a" => "Ref_B"
  405268013 => "481626839"
  "magnum_supports" => "Guneet Kaur"
  "test_1" => "Test 2"
  "001" => 0.02
  0 => 0
]

Comment: But array not contains `bsd`

Comment: yes but why????????